# Selecting distinct records having multiple properties

Tags: mysql

For following table data:

```
ID     | Property
=================
1      | Sweet
2      | Sweet
2      | Sour
3      | Hot
```

How can I get the ID's having `Property` Sweet *AND* Sour (in this example, 2)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be `group by` and `having`

```
select 
ID from table_name
where Property in('Sweet','Sour')
group by ID
having count(*)=2
```